# How can I know the process's memory usage

Tags: linux, memory, pid, proc

I'm now trying to analyze a process's memory usage, processes are written in C.
I want to know the size and the address for each variable which the process allocate.
I know the /proc/PID/maps is the good way to know about that things, but I don't know whether it can show me the information that I want to know or not.
For example, if the C program allocate memory like this,
*int i = 10;* or like this *float* f = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float))*, I want to get  a information like as follows *0x0000... 4byte*(for int i) and *0x0000...*(for float* f).
In my case, it's a not problem if the address is integrated. I mean I don't care if I declare 2 variables like as follows *int i,j;*, and the information is like as follows *0x000... 8byte*(the information about both i and j).
Does anyone know about process's memory usage like these or know about how to understand the /proc/PID/maps mean?

I would appreciate it if anyone teach me the things.

Regards.

PS:

I tired valgrind.
It's good debugger but I want to handle the data from my C code.
Is there any header file for valgrind, or maybe another tools?

Answer (score 0):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) is vary useful for you:

```
   Massif: a heap profiler
```

Note use of --pages-as-heap to measure all memory in a process